# VB.NET Regex.Replace not working

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string:

`str = "Liquid Cement Factory, LLC"`

and a Regex.Replace call:

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9/ -]", "")`

The comma is not removed after the replace call is made.  Does anyone know why?  I've tried different versions of the regex but none of them work.  Is this a VB.NET thing?  Is it a comma thing?

Comment: because your regex doesn't match a comma.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Regexs here as opposed to the much simpler [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function?

Comment: The "^" is supposed to mean a negative set, so it should be matching everything other than whats in that expression.  If I'm using that incorrectly please let me know.  I am using regex instead of replace because it is not just commas I want to get rid of but anything that's not in that regex expression. @basher

Comment: Are you handling the return value of the Replace function?

Answer (score 0):

the_lotus had the answer in the comments, I was not setting the string equal to my regex.replace call.  The solution is simply to do this:

`str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9/ -]", "")`

Something to always keep in mind, thank you.